# Element Song, updated with 118 names?

Tags: elements

Tom Lehrer’s [The Elements song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_(song)) ([listen](https://archive.org/details/elements_0)) mentions all elements up to Nobelium, and ends with the appology

> These are the only ones of which the news has come to Harvard,
>   And there may be many others, but they haven't been discovered.

Now that’s a bit *dated*. We can’t ignore trans-uranic elements when every bedroom in developed countries contains Americium-241, and now that official names have been ratified for all elements through period 7, I can hope that an updated song will be available.

Are there any such songs, whether a revision of the original or based on a new melody, or any known efforts underway to complete one?

Comment: I have downvoted. I personally really don't think this is on topic here, it is not an actual chemistry question. (But I'll hold back on the close hammer.) Would you consider coming to chat for these things?

Comment: While I believe this is on topic, downvoted because the answer is found by simply googling.

Comment: Americium is in the original song though...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question for the main site. This is the sort of thing which should be asked in chat.

Comment: Regarding close-vote: A good policemen/moderator/...  does not blindy enforce the rules, but allows an exception from time to time. In particular, when the rule violation does not really bother anyone, is especially popular and is a clear one-time exception.

Comment: @mhchem No, a good moderator sits back and only handles extremely clear-cut cases or those in which unresolved flags have been raised. It is the community’s job to decide whether this is on-topic or nur and it currently has accumulated three close votes (and two leave-open votes in the review queue). I think, it’s safe to say the community’s split on the subject.

Answer (score 7):

The NEW Periodic Table Song (Updated)
AsapSCIENCE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgVQKCcfwnU

Comment: Whilst this song may technically be on similar subject matter, it's nothing like the original song. Much like many of his works, it was inherently comedic.

Answer (score 5):

The Wikipedia page you linked to, links to [the song's text](http://www.guntheranderson.com/v/data/elements.htm) which has an alternative ending containing 3 more elements.

> [Alternate ending:]
>
> Lawrencium and Hahnium and lastly Rutherfordium
>   If there are any others, I'm afraid I haven't heardium